# How to make group row's cells editable

Tags: ag-grid

Is it possible to make group row's cells editable. 
Here is the example :
https://embed.plnkr.co/jd1xsC/

In above example we can see that group rows cells Supplier/Quantity are non-editable and only leaf node cells are editable.

Does ag-grid provide some grid option to make group rows editable ?

Answer (score 18):

Set **enableGroupEdit** to true in GridOptions to allow editing of groups.

Comment: Do you know what is the callback for group changes?

Comment: @Pedrammarandi did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Jstuff I made my custom cell renderers

Comment: @Jstuff  the callback for any cell value change (including group changes) is `onCellValueChanged`.

Comment: @davidvnog I inspected the params when onCellValueChanged is called for a group column cell and the .value (which usually stores the new value) is undefined

Comment: .newValue and .value are not updated accordingly, but you may find the updated info in .data